# How to integrate a Python model into a Spark module in Java?

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, machine-learning

I am developing a bachelor's degree thesis project on predictive analytics in the industrial sector based on Apache Spark and Apache Kafka. My job is to train an SVLM model with a new dataset and integrate (load) it into the Spark module in Java.

I have already made the model in Python and tried to save it in `.pkl` but I can't find the way to load it into the Java code like this:

```
LSVMModel = SVMModel.load(jsc.sc(), "javaSVMWithSGDModel");
```

I wanted to know if there is a way to integrate a ML Python model into Java code.

Comment: Your question is too broad. What are your specific requirements? How did you implement the model in python (can you export your model to [`onnx`](https://onnx.ai/))? Could you sent a batch job over kafka to python for inference (or streaming with pyspark)? Or use a serving layer?

Comment: How would you do it in Python? Maybe you can add a bit more to your listing? Can you make an example without the Kafka part that would be easier?